# I have a weird behavior with angular 2 rc4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

> The form validation is triggerd only before the ngModel gets updated
>   is there a option which I should set ? As I'm typing the validation is triggered 
>   before updating the ngModel

```
<input type="password" class="form-control"
                               [class.backend-error]="!accountModel.password.valid"
                               [placeholder]="passwordLabel"
                               (ngModelChange)="syncModel($event, accountModel.password.key, password.valid)"
                               [(ngModel)]="accountModel.password.value"
                               required 
                               pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$" 
                               minlength="6"
                               name="password"  #password="ngModel"/>
```

> Should I move all the validation to js ?